# Set function output as a variable for another function (GAS)

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets, input, output

Thanks in advance for helping me with this.

In Google Apps Script I wish to use the output of function rowOfEmployee as a variable (editrow) for function saveData

Can someone help me do this? I'm sure it's something really simple and obvious and I will probably kick myself for not working it out haha

Here are my two codes:

```
  var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var data = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var employeesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Save");
  var employee = employeesheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][0] == employee){
      Logger.log((i+1))
      return i+1;
    }
  }
  
}
function saveData() {
  var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var data = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var employeesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Save");
  var employee = employeesheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var editrow = rowOfEmployee //Here I want to take the output from the previous function rowOfEmployee
  var col = datasheet.getLastColumn();
  var target = datasheet.getRange(editrow,col +1);
  var saveEntry = employeesheet.getRange("B2").getValue();

  saveEntry.copyTo(target, {contentsOnly:true})

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `Array.indexOf()`, like this:

```js
function saveData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const employeeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Save');
  const employee = employeeSheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const names = dataSheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat();
  const targetIndex = names.indexOf(employee);
  if (targetIndex === -1) {
    ss.toast(`Name '${employee}' cannot be found.`);
    return;
  }
  dataSheet.getRange(targetIndex + 1, dataSheet.getLastColumn() + 1)
    .setValue(employeeSheet.getRange('B2').getValue());
  ss.toast(`Data saved.`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to lunch it from that loop? You have to do it the other way, not from saveData, but from the first function.

Name the function as `function saveData(editRow)` and call it from your loop by naming it and putting inside the variable: `saveData(i+1)`

PS: delete the definition of editRow in your function, the line that says `var editRow...`

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for helping out! Sadly, I'm not quite following your instructions, would you mind explaining in a little more detail? I'm confused about which functions I need to adjust. Thanks!